# Are JSlinks available for Sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink

Just wondering if JSlinks can be used with the online version of Sharepoint?

Comment: are you facing any errors?

Comment: Just looking into options at the moment - this was the original issue - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105371/auditing-for-opening-or-downloading-documents-unavailable-on-sp-online-alterna

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JSLink is available in Office 365 SharePoint 2013 online.

But be aware that only one method to attach a JSLink is available via the GUI, that is adding a JSLink to a particular view of a Web Part.

Other methods, like attaching a JSLink to a Site Column, require client-side code either via CSOM or JavaScript OM.